# How to clear background color of previously seelected text?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have `div` element with multiple lines of text. User can select texts using the mouse. I have javascript that sets the background color of the selected text when user click on a `btnChangeColor` button.

```
 $(function(){
        var result = [];

        $("#btnChangeColor").click(function () {       

        let currentColor = "red";
        if (window.getSelection()) {
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            var selectedText = range.toString();
            var startOffset = range.startOffset;
            var endOffset = startOffset + selectedText.length;
         
            var obj = {
                Id: "SomeUniqueIdPerSelection",
                start: startOffset,
                end: endOffset,
                text: selectedText
            }
            
            result.push(obj);            
            
            document.designMode = "on";
            //if (range) {
            //    sel.removeAllRanges();
            //    sel.addRange(range);
            //}
            
            // Colorize text
            document.execCommand("BackColor", false, currentColor);
            
            // Set design mode to off
            document.designMode = "off";
        }    
    })
})
```

The scripts stores the selection with unique id in an array.
There is another button on the same page. When user click, I want to clear the background color of the particular selection. Assume that `SomeUniqueIdPerSelection` is supplied as parameter

```
$("btnClearBtn").click(function(){    
    let id = GetSelectionId();
    let selected = result.find(x=>x.Id === id);
    //How do i clear the background color of this selection
})
```

Comment: Why not change the `::selection` color with css? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection

Comment: @rishi `::selection` is only applicable for currently selected content, here is a history of selected content while keeping the styling for that content.